$F'/K'$ and $F/K$ be algebraic function fields (of one variable), $F⊆F'$, $K⊆K'$. Does $F'/F$ be finite separable implies the same for $K'/K$.
This problem comes from from Stichtenoth's Algebraic Function Fields and Codes, the beginning of Section 3.4.
Let $F'/K'$ and $F/K$ be algebraic function fields (of one variable), $F⊆F'$, $K⊆K'$. Does $F'/F$ be finite separable extension implies the same for $K'/K$. (K and K' are full constant field.)
My progress：
Lemma 3.1.2 of Stichtenoth's Algebraic Function Fields and Codes. Let $F'/K'$ be an algebraic extension of $F/K$. Then the following hold:
(a) $K'/K$ is algebraic and $F \cap K' = K$.
(b) $F'/K'$ is a finite extension of $F/K$ if and only if $[K':K] < \infty$.
(c) Let $F_1 := FK'$. Then $F_1/K'$ is a constant field extension of $F/K$, and $F'/K'$ is a finite extension of $F_1/K'$ (having the same constant field).
The finiteness of $K'/K$ is clear by Lemma 3.1.2(b) of Stichtenoth's Algebraic Function Fields and Codes).
As for the separability, my intuition is as follows:
Conjecture:
For any $x\in K'$, $\min(x,K)=\min(x,F)$. (Note that $K'/K$ is algebraic since $F'/F$ is, by Lemma 3.1.2(a) of Stichtenoth's Algebraic Function Fields and Codes)
If this conjecture is true, then the proof of separablity is direct. However, I have no further results.
Thanks in advance for any help!


Please don't use overlarge font. 2. please do not use images to convey relevant mathematical information not otherwise present in your post. This is why.


It's possible the large bold font was accidental. A paragraph break removed the font change.

Thanks very much for your suggestion！ I have made adjustment accordingly. The content of the image are presented by text now.

I believe it's true:
Let $x \in K'$ and $f(X):=\min(x, K) \in K[X]$. Suppose that $f(X)=p(X)q(X)$, where $p(X), q(X) \in F[X]$ are monic irreducible polynomials over $F$ and $\deg p(X), \deg q(X) \ge 1$, i.e., $f(X)$ is not irreducible over $F$. Let $p(X)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_iX^i$ and $q(X)=\sum_{j=1}^m b_jX^j$ ($a_n=1=b_m$).
Moreover each root of $p(X)$ or $q(X)$ is also a root of $f(X)$; in part., the roots of $p(X)$ and $q(X)$ are algebraic over $K$.
Since the coefficients $a_i$'s (resp., $b_j$'s) are equal to sums and products of the roots of $p(X)$ (resp., $q(x)$), we have $a_i$ and $b_j$ are algebraic over $K$ for all $i$, $j$.
Thus $a_i, b_j \in \bar{K} \cap F=K$ for any $i,j$, since $K$ is the full constant field of $F$. Hence $f(X)=p(X)q(X)$ in $K[X]$, a contradiction. Therefore, $f(X)$ is irreducible and follows that $f(X)=\min(x, F)$, by uniqueness of the minimal polynomial.
(here it is assumed that $F \subseteq F' \subseteq \Omega$, where $\Omega$ is a fixed algebraically closed field for some steps to make sense).

More directly: Let $x \in K'$ and $f(X) \in K[X]$ be the minimal polynomial of $x$. We can see $f(X)$ as a polynomial in $F[X]$ and $x$ as an element  $F'$, which is a root of $f(X)$. Since $F'/F$ is separable, $f$ has no multiple roots. Hence $K'/K$ is also separable.

Thank you very much for your response. I believe it is a correct and elegant proof. It is of great help to me, resolving a long-standing issue I had.
I also want to apologize for seeing your response too late (today).
With my best regards!
